# QGIS export to KML

Tags: qgis, export, google-earth

How can I create [image: sample exported .shp file in kml] this kind of output in Google Earth from QGIS, where I can show the labels of the exported file in KML?

Comment: Right click on layer, "save as", choose KML. Or would you like to specify your question further?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: @ErikLohmann: i already did that but when i saved it in .kml it just showing the lines in google earth and no labels are showing.

Comment: Does your shape/kml contain single lines, or simply the whole grid? To me it seems to be either an export/data issue with QGis (as in, your data does not contain the desired label values separately) or a visualisation issue with Earth (as in, you didn't find the right label option/column yet).

Comment: @ErikLohmann: in qgis i set the labels to be displayed but when i exported it in google as .kml file the labels are gone.

Comment: That is because Earth does not use style settings from QGis. Without example data it is rather hard to show you exactly how to set the labels in Earth.